# Jquery script freezing browser but working

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, live

i'm trying to make a live search for my mobile website, I don't want to query the database every time a user type a letter so I created a ordered list with all the names that can be searched for and i'm looping through it with jquery, problem is that I have 3300 names and it's freezing the browser when it searches through them, can anyone give me a tip about better ways to do it? here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input#search").keyup(function(){
        var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;
            var html = "";
        $("ol.pacientes li").each(function(){
                    var nome_paciente = $(this).text();
                    if(nome_paciente.indexOf(filter.toUpperCase()) != -1){
                        html = html + " " + nome_paciente;
                    }

                    $('#pacientes_hint').html(html);
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the jQuery autocomplete version. You can load an array with all your names and pass it in to autocomplete, which will work on the fly.

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/

Comment: Thanks, just tried this and it was fast enough, having trouble with customizing output now, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could change your each to:

```
var text = $("ol.pacientes li:contains(\""+filter.toUpperCase()+"\")").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).join(' ');
$('#pacientes_hint').text(text);
```

Besides being shorter, the only improvement will be setting the contents of `$('#pacientes_hint')` only at the end, which could help.

Let me know if you need a more creative solution.

Comment: You should escape the input text: `filter.toUpperCase().replace('"', '\\"')`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you could move #pacientes_hint outside the each function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input#search").keyup(function(){
    var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;
        var html = "";
    $("ol.pacientes li").each(function(){
                var nome_paciente = $(this).text();
                if(nome_paciente.indexOf(filter.toUpperCase()) != -1){
                    html = html + " " + nome_paciente;
                } // end if


    }); // end each
     $('#pacientes_hint').html(html);
```

Then, you can define ol.pacientes as a variable before the keyup handler, so it doesn't look for it everytime and in the each function, search inside the variable:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var pacientes_list = $("ol.pacientes");
var pacientes_hint = $("#pacientes_hint");
$("input#search").keyup(function(){
    ...
    $("li", $(pacientes_list)).each(function(){ // search in the container
       ...     
    }); // end each
     $(pacientes_hint).html(html);
```

Comment: I tried this, the search got really faster, but not fast enough for the iphone browser, but thanks anyways